# How to iterate with index elegantly in Python, for string-matching a list of substrings inside text?

Tags: python, string-matching, idioms, sliding-window

`Text` is a large string, `patterns` is a list of short (fixed) strings.
My code is:

```
def BruteForcePatternMatching(text, patterns):
    indices = []
    for pattern in patterns:
        for index in range(len(text) - 1):
            slide = text[index : index + len(pattern) - 1]
            if pattern == slide:
                indices.append(index)
    return indices
```

My question is if there is a 'pythonic' way to extract a 'slide' from text, of iterated size.

Comment: This looks something like [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) except you're not searching the whole string. Is that more or less what you're trying to do?

Comment: What is `patterns`? A list of fixed strings you want to match inside text? or a list of regexes?

Comment: What's a "slide"? If you make up your own terminology you have to define it for us.

Comment: See edit. Sorry about the vagueness. By 'slide' I mean a substring of the string `text` of length n which shifts starting position along `text`.

Comment: @user6309: it will help you be understood if you use standard terminology. You want to match each of a list of fixed string patterns inside your text. Your code is trying to do it using a **sliding-window from index to end-of-string**, and testing for exact matches (string '==' operator). This is not a good idea because 'dog' will not match 'doggerel'. It's also very slow: your two nested loops test all N indices in text, and all P patterns; this will be order O(N*P).

Comment: Your `- 1` are incorrect - in both places. The first one could be replaced by `- len(pattern)`.  The pythonic way to do this though, is by using either string methods or the `re` module.

Comment: @smci I appreciate the help.
My intention was to use a sliding-window of every size, actually - starting from 'from index to index + 1' up to 'from index to end of string' - but I didn't accomplish that.

Comment: @thebjorn I'll look into both. Thank you

Comment: In general if you ever find yourself using a sliding-window, or nested loops, or iterating over indices, each of those is a "code smell"/ anti-pattern that there is probably a better way.

Comment: @smci I'll keep in that in mind. I had that feeling.

Comment: Just another idiomatic point: don't call `patterns` patterns unless it actually contains regexes. In this case it doesn't, so just call it `words`/`substrings`/`wordlist`/...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to find matches to a list, `patterns`, inside your text.

If `patterns` is just fixed strings, use `string.find()` (although note that will only find the first occurrence - see below).

```
s = 'cat dog cow dog' # Note 'dog' occurs multiply
s.find('dog')
4
s.find('cow')
8
s.find('cat')
0
```

More generally, if patterns either has regexes, or has duplicate fixed strings, use `re.findall/iter()`. See the many duplicate questions here for examples.

```
import re
pat = re.compile(r'(cat|dog|cow)')
pat.findall("The cat and cow sat on the dog's catalog of doggerel")
# ['cat', 'cow', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog']
```

And if you also need the indices where matches occur, use `re.finditer()` as @khachik showed.

Note we combined all the patterns into one regex, then used one `re.findall()` call to search for all matches of every pattern inside all of text.
Your current code is very inefficient: it's trying to test for string-equality by running a sliding-window over text, and has nested loops: one covers all N indices in text, and all P patterns; this will be order O(N*P), which is not scalable.

Comment: That's pretty great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your patterns don't contain any special regex characters or are regexes themselves:

```
import re
indices = [(m.start(), m.end()) for m in re.finditer("|".join(patterns), text)]
```